# Could not write JSON: nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am doing prototype of spring project where I am reading the data from database using spring JPA CRUD repository. 
I have below urls

- localhost/account/addaccount -- add new account to db
- localhost/account/all -- to get all accounts from db

I am able to push data to db and also able to retrieve data for only single record. While retrieving data from db with multiple records getting below error.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 03 23:36:07 CST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[1]->Accounts.Account["accountNumber"])
```

How can I figure out the issue?

Comment: can you share your and error cause

Comment: can i ask why you using json parser

Comment: you are right there is not need to json parser, spring boot automatically returns data in json format. Thank you